# RewriteRule to accept 3 parameters but 2nd & 3rd param are optional

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/parameter-1
```

I have this htaccess RewriteRule -

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
```

The htaccess file is inside [MyFolder] and this only accept a single parameter.

How can do a RewriteRule to accept 3 parameters but the 2nd and 3rd parameters are optional so that the following 4 URLs are ALL possible

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-2/param-3
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-2
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-3
```

Edit : Ill make it that PARAM3 always starts with the word [pop]

Thanks

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer if this works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?([a-z0-9\-]+)?/?([a-z0-9\-]+)?/?$ index.php?c=$1&d=$2&e=$3 [NC,L]`

This would work for:

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-2/param-3
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-2
```

with `$_GET[d]` and `$_GET[e]` having as value `''` in certain cases.

Having:

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-2
mydomain.com/MyFolder/param-1/param-3
```

Seems impossible to me as is, how can you know if the second is param 2 or param 3 ?

Comment: What if Ill make it in such a way that PARAM3 always starts with the word [pop]. What will me the RewriteRule. Thanks

Comment: then : `^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?([a-z0-9\-]+)?/?(pop[a-z0-9\-]+)?/?$` should work.

Comment: Oh by the way leave the `pop` outside the `()` if you don't want it in the GET value, `pop([a-z0-9\-]+)`

Comment: What do you mean by "if you dont want it in the GET value"? I need a RewriteRule that can trap the 4 possible URLs as I mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: I meant do you want the string 'popValue' or 'Value' in `$_GET['e']` ? first case go with (pop[a-z0-9\-]+) second case go with 'pop([a-z0-9\-]+)'. Will be catch in the variable only what is inside the '()'.